# How to set the response of a form post action to a iframe source?

Tags: javascript, post, iframe

I have a form and an iframe. I want to set the source of the iframe on form submit to a 3rd party payment gateway url. Also, onSubmit a javascript function is called. I want to display the response of the form submit within a iframe rather than in the parent window. Kindly guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<form target="frame" onsubmit="document.getElementById('frame').style.display = 'block';">
</form>

<iframe id="frame" name="frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

I think that's all you need ;)

Comment: where do i set the source for the iframe? Is it not required? Thanks.

Comment: If your iframe is not to display anything before submission of the form, you don't set it at all. You only define the action="" for the form element. If you wish to show the iframe all the time, however, I'd recommend removing the style attribute `display: none` and set an attribute `src="http://your.src/path/there"`.

Comment: Initially i dont need to display anything in the iframe. On submit, i have to send a request to the paymentgateway, the response of which i need to display in the iframe and this is the time i need to set the src for the iframe. So as per the example, i need to do something like : `code`(onsubmit="document.getElementById('frame').src = '<?php echo $response ?>';") . Is this the right way to set the src for the iframe? Other problem i am facing is that on submiting the form, a js function is called , where do i call this? Can i append it to onsubmit?

Comment: i tried this code [link](http://pastebin.com/zJR75Lbi) The src of the iframe gets set with the input type button onclick event but doesnot work with input type submit and form onsubmit event. Is there any way to set the iframe src with onsubmit event.Thanks

Comment: The source of the iframe is set to the response as soon as you set the form's target to frame, the name of the iframe. You don't need setting its source manually via javascript onsubmit. I suggest using the exact code I posted earlier ;) As stated, if the form's target is the iframe, the form will submit to the url provided in its action parameter and load it within the iframe. You only need to make sure you display the iframe after submitting the form ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, i did not set the action="" for the form and hence the problem i was facing. Its working now.

Comment: Any idea how do i pass the control from the iframe back to the parent window? On form submit, the ifrom displays a payment gateway page. On processing the response, the paymentgateway redirects to a url. Will that be loaded within the iframe or in the parent page? If it loads in the iframe, how do i make it load in the parent window?

Comment: <script>top.location.href='...'</script> if using JS, or <a href="" target="_top" >...</a> if using a simple link. If using a form, just set its target to _top.

Comment: @arik-so let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3025/discussion-between-nithin-and-arik-so)